# How to write unit tests in angular for pipe and map?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I need to write unit tests in angular for pipe and map.

```
    public getDataById(Id): Observable<Data[]> {
    const url = "my url";
    return this.authHttpService.get(url, null, this.scope)
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          this.data= List<Data>(response.body);
          return this.data.toArray();
        })
      );
  }
```

Could any one please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The question here would be how can we test a component which uses a service and we are using pipe and map here. FIrst thing is we may need to mock the authHttpService. You can follow this to understand more: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/

And now when it comes to unit testing, we need to assert something. So you can check whether getDataById has the data you mocked or not.

I hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: I already covered unit tests for service. but I need to cover it for map and pipe

Answer (score 0):

First mock your service to return mock data. Adapt your mock data so it can be processed with pipe and map.

```
const result = {
  data: [
    {id: 0, name: 'Temp Data 1'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Temp Data 2'},
  ]
};

export class authHttpServiceMock{
  constructor() {
  }

  get() {
    return Observable.of(result);
  }

}
```

Second step call your  getDataById(Id) method in spec file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is regarding coverage of pipe and map, So I assume you already know how to mock a service.

First step: Always mock what you are returning inside a map, In your case it will be
Let us say **response = { status: [] }**

Second step:

```
    httpClientSpy.get.mockReturnValue(of(respone));
```

Third step: Call the method and subscribe it and expect the result that observable will be returning

```
  instance.getDataById(Id).subscribe((result) => {
    expect(result).toEqual([]);
  });
```